# Is there any possibility to change the style for Datepicker control in Smartface App Studio

Tags: smartface.io

Want to change the style for the Datepicker control. Is there any possibility for this?

While using the app on Samsung Tab, i am getting two calender's on datepicker control. This confusing while selecting or changing the date. Can we get only one calendar rather than two?
[image]

can any one please help me to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Smartface, datepicker's format can't be changed. 
You can use mask in order to change date format of the function only, but it will not affect the style of datepicker object.

Comment: Thanks merve, I added detail info to my question. Could you please look in it.

Comment: Ok, it seems like a device specific bug. I tested with Samsung Galaxy Tab3, and didn't face the problem. Can you please give more information about your device?

Comment: Sure. Its Samsung SM-T331, Android version: 5.1.1. Let me know if you require any other information.

Comment: Vijay, now I faced the same thing with a Lollipop device. It will be fixed in the next release. Thanks for your report.

Comment: Thanks merve :) When can we expect the next release? Any idea?

Comment: Most probably it will be released in two weeks.